# Magento - Fastest way to check if store exists

Tags: magento

I have a store code, how do I check if that store exists? I tried:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeCode);
```

But if the store is not existed, it just print the 404 page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode);
if ($store->getId()) {
    //the store exists
}
else {
    //the store does not exist
}
```